Netbeans on 2+ computers: How to share SFTP connections
I work in Netbeans on up to 3 computers (all Windows PCs).  It's just me working, so no need to version control.  The "local" copy is on my NAS, so no matter what computer I use, I work on the same files.  I've been doing that for years and it works fine, I do not need to work on my C: drive.
What I need is:

A way of sharing all SFTP connections with the 3 machines (this might be easy I don't know).
When I use another machine (not my main one) it seems to have forgotten the SFTP connection that is selected in "Run Configuration" > "Remote Connection" so I have to re-set it to the correct one.

I am selecting the Known Hosts file which is obviously shared between them all, not quite sure what that is doing.
